# Domain modelling, should Domain be included as a model?

Tags: architecture, model

Let's say we have a domain consisting of customers, their orders and each orders orderitem.

Thus we have in our domain model:
Customer
Order 
OrderItem

What would the consequences, pros and cons be of also having Domain as a model?

That is, 
Domain (containing several customers)
Customer
Order
OrderItem

Perhaps it could be used to store metadata/configurations for an instance of a domain?
What else?

Con; Added complexity

Is this regarded as an anti-pattern somehow?

Anyways, since this board prefers questions that can be answered and not just discussed- my question is;
Is this good or bad practice?
(and why?)

edit: I just realized that if Domain is included in the domain model then the actual domain is expanded and no longer the domain "Domain" refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "domain" you mean some business-meaningful way of grouping together customers, like customer type, or discount group, or something like that, then sure, make a parent table.  Oftentimes customers have multiple foreign keys of this sort into multiple "domains".

But it might be easier to answer if you told us how customers are grouped into a "domain", what makes a customer a member of a particular domain, and how it distinguishes them from other customers.

Because unless there is a meaningful difference between the groupings, then it is an abstraction contraption and the answer is no, don't do it.